# how to use flask_sqlalchemy signal to log actions to db?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying to use sqlalchemy signals to log db actions to actions_log table
but i got this error

**sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.**

```
#acionslog model

class ActionsLog(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    object = db.Column(db.String(50))
    action = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    user_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))

 
#__init__.py

@models_committed.connect
def log_action(sender, changes):

   if current_user.is_authenticated:
      print(sender)
      print(changes)

      instance = changes[0][0]
      action = changes[0][1]
    
      from app.backend.user.models import ActionsLog

      log = ActionsLog()
      log.object =  str(instance)
      log.action = action
      log.user_id = current_user.id

      db.session.add(log)
      db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `@before_models_committed.connect` instead of `@models_committed.connect`
2. Delete line `db.session.commit()`